# Unable to load DLL 'Xeneth.dll'

Tags: c#, dll

I get following error message:
*Unable to load DLL 'Xeneth.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)*

Although the Xeneth.dll has been added under the references I get this error message on this codeline:

```
XCHANDLE = (uint)DllImports.XC_OpenCamera(CameraName, StatusCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
```

thanks in advance for the help..!

Comment: Do you copy this dll to your build directory?

Comment: In the properties of the referenced DLL, is "Copy Local" set to "true"?

Comment: @Sayse the dll is in the bin/Debug folder

Comment: @spender "copy local" is set to true - yes

Answer (score 1):

That error code is a COM error wrapping the Win32 error code `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. This means that either `Xeneth.dll` or one of its dependencies cannot be found on the DLL search path.

You should consult the documentation for this library to work out where it must be deployed. Usually, and most sensibly, unmanaged DLLs should be placed in the same directory as the executable file. Doing so ensures that they are located.

If doing that does not help, then you may need to deal with missing dependencies. Again check the documentation. Do you need to install an MSVC runtime on which this DLL depends?

If all this fails then you might try using a tool like Dependency Walker, and use its profiling mode to try to work out what is missing. However, I do suggest that you start with the library documentation first. It's always best to follow and understand the instructions.